# selenium webdriver is not able to identify elements due to page self refresh

Tags: page-refresh

I am using selenium webdriver and java. my scenario is that "need to click on photo to enlarge and then need to close it. once I closed this, the page will return to the home page(previous) and then not able to identify the elements that were identified before. I tried webdriverwait and no luck. but it is working when I tried manually in firebug with same locators. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refreshing page, changing it's content (usually occurs in menus) element which was previously identified using webdriver will be not accessible any more (on trying to interact with it , you'll get "Element is not longer attached to the DOM" or StateElementReference exceptions. To avoid it, after changing content of that element (in your case page) you need to re-find element again using same selectors as before (this is some kind of update). Always works for me.